# It is possible to remove the top name banner when im using tabs?

Tags: java, android

I just wanted to know if it possible to remove the top name bar when im using tabs?
I tryed to remove it by using

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

but its crashing and telling me that the tabs are null, its logical.

Is there anther way for this?

http://i62.tinypic.com/2dijbys.png

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Add this code before setContentView
it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

To disable the icon and title in the ActionBar.

Note if you are using App Compat (i.e., extending `ActionBarActivity`), you'd instead use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```